# WIX MSP - Missing Version and Publisher in Control Panel

Tags: wix, patch, msi-patch

I have a product MSI with version 1.1.500.0.

On top of this I have created an MSP using WIX based on a contract predefined with Manufacturer Name and Version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Patch Id="*" AllowRemoval="yes" Manufacturer="My Publisher" MoreInfoURL="www.mysite.com" TargetProductName="My Product" DisplayName="My Product Display Name" Description="My Description" Classification="hotfix">
    <Media Id="12200" Cabinet="RTM.cab">
      <PatchBaseline Id="RTM" />
    </Media>
    <PatchFamily Id="fam1" Version="1.1.9058.27799" Supersede="no"></PatchFamily>
  </Patch>
</Wix>
```

Opening this MSP with ORCA I can see the details correctly set.

However when I install the Patch the version and publisher are blank in the "View installed updates" list from Control Panel:

From the install log:

```
Executing op: ProductRegister(UpgradeCode={GUID},
VersionString=1.1.500.0,,,InstallLocation=C:\MyFolder\,
InstallSource=C:\Kit\,
Publisher=My Publisher,,,,NoModify=1,,,,Contact=My Publisher,,,,EstimatedSize=75216,,,,)
```

Can you maybe guide me on what can I check further?

Thanks!